# Schema design suitable for big system

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am designing a follow feature for my online books reading which had about 100k books. So I wonder which is a better way to use MongoDB.

1. Push all books followed into array and store as 1 document. When reach max document we split into another document
2. When the user followed a book we create a need documents

Please help me point out the Pros and Cons of each way or a new way better than both above way to reach this situation

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {comicConnection} = require('../db');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserFollowsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
    follow: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Books' }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = comicConnection.model(
  'UserFollows',
  UserFollowsSchema,
  'UserFollows'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the second method, you have better access and you can do calculations more easily.
Whenever a user follows a book, create a document that the user follows the book, and so on.
Then you can use this to find out how many books you have followed:

```
User.countDocuments({user:{USER-ID}});
```

Comment: I also can count the length of array to know how many books user have followed

Comment: When using second method it let me remembers like I am using mysql design. So no way to take advantage of nosql with this situation?

Comment: In order to find out if a person has followed a book, you have to read a document that has a long array from the database, and this puts pressure on your server.
But when you save separately, you can check separately and there is no double pressure on the server.

Comment: But when you find the list of the books users have followed instead find one document in 100k document of 100k users you have to find it in about a millions of documents that make more times. So I wonder which way is better